# spamassassin with sendmail: spamass-milter or spampd?

Tags: sendmail, spam, spamassassin

I want to integrate my sendmail MTA (relaying only, no local mailboxes) with spamassassin. Sendmail box sits between internal MS Exchange server and internet. So, I see two options for doing this (or there are more?), depicted bellow schematically:

1. use spamass-milter

> ```
>   sender -> sendmail -> exchange server
>
>       where sendmail talk to spamass-milter -> spamc -> spamd (spamassassin)
> ```

2. use spampd (spamassassin proxy daemon, do not confuse it with spamd)

> ```
>  sender -> sendmail -> spampd -> exchange server
>
>         where spampd talks to spamassassin
> ```

I want to know your opinion: which option is better, what are the pros and cons of each one?

Comment: is sendmail a requirement or are other options such as postfix being considered?

Comment: I have already implemented sendmail and want to stay with it.

Comment: ok if you change your mind consider this: http://assp.sourceforge.net/... actually that works with sendmail too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am executing SpamAssassin via [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

We use [policyd-weight](http://www.policyd-weight.org/) for filtering. Its works fine. But i think solution one is enough.

Comment: But isn't it something completely different from spamassassin?

Comment: its a spamfilter you can read the specification on the site ;). we use policyd-weight -> spamass (if you need it) for Postfix. Aber them you can make a relay to your exchange server.